# Scheduled Task Powershell Script - Runs OK as user account, but not as SYSTEM

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to run a Powershell script as the `SYSTEM` account as a scheduled task, and the task runs OK, but the script runs incorrectly <s>because it does not load some Citrix Powershell snap-ins that are needed</s> when run as SYSTEM, but runs OK as my user account.

The script does a check to load the Citrix snap-ins, but those do not appear to work when run as `SYSTEM`.

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Citrix.Common.Commands" -EA silentlycontinue) -eq $null) {
try { Add-PSSnapin Citrix.* -ErrorAction Stop }
catch { write-error "Error Citrix.* Powershell snapin"; Return }
```

<s>Is there anything special I need to do to get those Snap-ins loaded correctly?</s> I'm calling the script like this, if it matters: `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\path\to\script.ps1`.

**EDIT:** From running (Get-PSSnapin -registered).count as both `SYSTEM` and my user account, I can see that the snap-ins are loaded correctly, but still can't figure out why the script behaves differently.

OS is Server 2016, version 1607, this is the script: https://gist.github.com/4oo4/85cec464e123d7f2793745e662d6e7ab

Comment: Why do you need all this tests? just do `Add-PSSnapin Citrix.*` if it already exist why do you care? it will just ignore them, also runing test on my machine with citrix servers: `(Get-PSSnapin -Registered).Count` has the same count with regular admin or with system account user, so it should'nt make a diffferent

Comment: Not sure why they have it that way, it's someone else's script that we've modified. I'll simplify it like you suggest and see if that helps.

Comment: @Avshalom Thanks for the tip to check what Snap-ins are actually registered, the problem looks to be something different. I updated the question.

Comment: Please specify the OS script is running on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't the answer why your specific script doesn't work under the SYSTEM account but explains how you might *troubleshoot* your (or any other) PowerShell Script under the SYSTEM account.

> Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish,
>   and you feed him for a lifetime.

The whole thing around this, is that you can actually open a interactive PowerShell command prompt under the SYSTEM account were you probably not aware of.

### Run PowerShell as SYSTEM

There are a few ways to start a interactive PowerShell command prompt but probably the easiest one is using [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

**Using [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)**

- [Download
  PsTools](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip)
- Extract `PSTools.zip` and just copy `PsExec` into your executable path
- Run `PowerShell` *as Administrator* (accept the `User AccountControl` prompt)
- In the PowerShell administrator window, give the command: `.\PsExec -i -s -d PowerShell`
- A new `PowerShell` command window will open:
  [image: PowerShell as SYSTEM]
  <sub>(Type `WhoAmI` to confirm the current account)</sub>

From here you can **troubleshoot** the specific script:

- Are there any errors when running the specific script?
- Does it hang or crash at a specific command?
- Are there any differences with running it under a user account?

If it appears that the script runs actually fine in the SYSTEM window, then I would check for any errors in the `Task Scheduler`:

- Select `Task Scheduler Local` - `Task Scheduler Library` in the left pane
- Select your task in the middle top pane
- (Make sure you have `Display All Task History` in the right pane `Enabled`)
- In the middle bottom pane check the events in the `history` tab

Comment: Thanks for the tip! By running the script interactively as SYSTEM, I can see that I was getting an "Insufficient Administrative Privileges" error. My mistake appears to be that the Citrix Delivery controller goes off of AD Permissions (and Roles/Scopes) versus the local accounts on the Delivery Controller itself. And you're right, I was way too vague with my question, and this will definitely help with troubleshooting in the future.

Comment: I'm getting an error trying the above command: `Error establishing communication with PsExec service on XXXX: The specified network name is no longer available.` (I'm running from pwsh as Admin.)