# Ps1 script not executing properly when using Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to use Task Scheduler to run a PS1 script, however it does not seem to work. When I run the task PowerShell opens briefly, but the script does not run. When I execute the script manually it runs as expected.

- Task Scheduler settings:

  - Action: `Start a Program`
  - Program: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
  - Arguments: `D:\Powershell\test.ps1`
  - Configure for: `Win10`

Script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Timer = [System.Timers.Timer]::new(3000)
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action{
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{TAB}")
}

$Timer.Start()
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Arguments: `D:\Powershell\test.ps1` should be `-f "D:\Powershell\test.ps1"` tho, if this is running as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` I don't think it will work

Comment: If the task runs under the **SYSTEM** account (add that detail to the question), [test whether it actually works under the system account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612478/1701026). Also add `-ExecutionPolicy bypass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, to execute a script (`*.ps1`) you just need to call the [`-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-file----filepath-args) Argument or `-f` for short  however, doing only this, will not result in what you want (a task that is Alt-Tabbing *indefinitely*?) because the task would end as soon as the `ObjectEvent` was registered.

As a workaround, you need to find a way to keep the scheduled task alive, ergo, keep the `powershell.exe` process running in the background alive.

I'll list a few option so you can decide which one you like more or *fits your need*.

1. The easiest one, in my opinion, is just to add the [`-NoExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-noexit) argument to your task, this will keep the task alive indefinitely, until, manually ending it / reboot / shutdown / killing the `powershell.exe` process / etc.

   - Program: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
   - Arguments: `-WindowStyle Hidden -NoExit -f "D:\testing\script.ps1"`
2. Adding a loop on the code, for this you have many options, for example
   `Get-EventSubscriber | Wait-Event` which, same as before, will keep the task alive indefinitely.

   - Program: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
   - Arguments: `-WindowStyle Hidden -f "D:\testing\script.ps1"`

   ```bash
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

   $Timer = [System.Timers.Timer]::new(3000)
   Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {
       [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}')
   }

   $Timer.Start()

   Get-EventSubscriber | Wait-Event
   ```
3. A loop that would keep the task alive for `X` days / hours / minutes:

   - Program: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
   - Arguments: `-WindowStyle Hidden -f "D:\testing\script.ps1"`
   - Code (you can use a `[datetime]` object instead of `[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]` here, your call):

   ```
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

   $Timer = [System.Timers.Timer]::new(3000)
   Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {
       [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}')
   }

   $Timer.Start()

   $elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

   do {
       Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5
   }
   until($elapsed.Elapsed.Minutes -ge 60)

   $elapsed.Stop()
   exit 0
   ```
4. Last one, similar to the example before but not using an `ObjectEvent` at all:

   - Program: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
   - Arguments: `-WindowStyle Hidden -f "D:\testing\script.ps1"`

   ```
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

   $elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

   do {
       [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{TAB}')
       Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 3000
   }
   until($elapsed.Elapsed.Seconds -ge 30)

   $elapsed.Stop()
   exit 0
   ```

Comment: I was able to make this work using your suggestions, thank you for this!

The task of alt+tabbing indefinitely was just an easy way for me to identify if the loop was actually running continuously. I really wanted to work through the process of scheduling a task that occurs when the computer goes idle - and in some situation use a loop to continue to do something until interruption.

Comment: @hcsuaf if the answer was helpful to you considerer [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)