# How to run powershell script under System context or with high privilege?

Tags: c#, powershell, admin

Im trying to run one PowerShell script using C# application.

```
Get-CimInstance MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus -Namespace root\wmi |select PredictFailure
```

I am running this script from c# application which is not running as admin and this script is giving me an error

> access denied-HRESULT 0x80041003,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand

On some R&D I got that Ciminstance need admin access to run so I wanted to know how to run `get-ciminstance` as non-admin user. Please suggest me any way to run this script as System or with highest privilege.

Comment: As **Admin** or as [**System**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612478/1701026)?

Comment: I want to run script as System

Comment: I am running this script from c# application which is not running as admin and this script is giving me an error(access denied-HRESULT 0x80041003,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand ). On some R&D I got that Ciminstance need admin access to run so I wanted to know how to run `get-ciminstance` as non-admin user.

Comment: You can set the set WMI namespace security using the [MMC snap-in located in the Control Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/setting-namespace-security-with-the-wmi-control)

Comment: Can we set this from script only? As we can't perform above operations because application is already installed on different machine. So we want modify our script only.

Comment: That is not possible (catch22): you will require admin privileges to change the security privileges...

Comment: Okay.. thank you