# PowerShell doesn't save and exit excel file when using windows scheduler

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I've been reading questions for days and I can't find an answer. I used Windows Scheduler to daily run an Rscript which creates an Excel file (but as this file has an XML problem for what I read in another question) but I can't use this file in PowerBI unless I open and save it, so Powershell and Windows Scheduler come to my rescue. But the problem appears when I schedule the task in Windows Scheduler. Because manually using the script below works perfectly, but if I make a test run in Windows Scheduler the file can't be successfully saved, so the process stucks with Excel asking me if I want to save the file.

I have this script to open my fresh Excel file and basically make no changes, then being saved and exit Excel. So, if I run this script manually from Powershell everything is fine, the file is opened, saved and closed just as I need.

```
$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("file location")
$Worksheet1 = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Worksheet1.Activate()
$Worksheet1.Cells.Item(1,22) = ""

$Workbook.Save("file location")
$Workbook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()

[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Worksheet1)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
Remove-Variable Excel
Remove-Variable Worksheet1
```

IF I CHANGE THIS PART OF THE SCRIPT, THE EXCEL FILE IS CLOSED BUT NOT SAVED.

```
$Workbook.Save("file location")
$Workbook.Close($false)
$Excel.Quit()
```

As I said before I don't why it happens when using the scheduler. Also I have tried modifying the script with saveas or even taking some parts out but same result.

Or do you know another solution for my problem at the beginning?

Comment: Without digging too deep into your code ... it is actually well known that the office programs are notorious for not working well with scheduled tasks. The best option for working with Excel files is to use the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) ... you don't even need an installed Excel for it.  ;-)

Comment: What is the user running script by Task Scheduler? There can be some problems with Excel execution under *SYSTEM* user.

Comment: If it does concern the **SYSTEM** account (which isn't mentioned), have a look here: [Scheduled Task Powershell Script - Runs OK as user account, but not as SYSTEM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612478/1701026).