# Get-ADUser result differs when running from SYSTEM user vs Admin user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Query:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(userpassword=*)(unixuserpassword=*))' -Properties * |     Select-Object samaccountname, description, UnixUserPassword, UserPassword, unicodePwd, msSFU30Name, msSFU30Password, os400-password
```

Results:
Running powershell as **SYSTEM** user:
Gives 5 users details
Getting only **userpassword** entries and not **unixuserpassword**

Running powershell as **Admin** user:
Gives 16 users details
Getting both **userpassword** and **unixuserpassword**

Can anyone point out which permission or config setting causing this behaviour?
Thanks.

Comment: You should be seeing 8 properties as you've specified just that. Does the call without the RHS pipe filter not give you what you're after? Permissions would be checked on the account objects themselves from AD

Comment: Are there any errors when [running as SYSTEM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612478/1701026)?

Comment: @iRon No errors while running

Comment: @AbrahamZinala ..yes i get 8 properties but for 5 users only while running as SYSTEM.

Comment: Is your computer in the same domain as the admin user? What happens if you add a `SearchBase`?

Comment: are you running script on a DC ? on basic domain member workstation or server SYSTEM is only a local user with local permissions.